# regular expression for numeric and special chacter check

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the code I have:-

```
   var exp = /[^0-9]/g;
    if (!exp.test(char)) {
        args.set_cancel(true);
```

I want to include special character check meaning I do not want special character to be entered (except backslash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `I do not want special character to be entered (except backslash).`

You need to define what makes a special character.

Though you can probably use this regex: (as per comments below)

**1st case:**

```
var exp1 = /^[a-z]+\\\\[a-z\d]+$/ig;
```

**Demo: http://regex101.com/r/kB1cN5**

**2nd case:**

```
var exp2 = /^((?!.*?\d)(?!.*?[^\w\s]).)+$/g;
```

Comment: All special character available on the keyboard

Comment: ok check the edited code now but you need to provide some sample input data.

Comment: He probably counts `_` as a special character too, which `\w` matches

Comment: Can you club it with the numeric check i posted in my code. I am sorry I am very bad in regex

Comment: @OGHaza: That's why I requested OP to provide some sample data.

Comment: @Bose_geek: So numbers should be allowed OR not allowed?

Comment: @Bose_geek: I am again requesting you to provide some expected and not-expected input data sample, otherwise we will be second guessing.

Comment: Numbers shoud NOT be allowed

Comment: Case 1 : In one text box i should be allowed like domain\user001. Domain any length slash username with some numbers and nothing else.
Case2 : rest just alphabets and NO numbers or special chars.

Comment: @Bose_geek: Ok check updated code. Now digits will NOT be allowed anywhere in the input.

Comment: requesting you to provide for case 1 as well ! And I guess your updated code will NOT allow special chars as well. testing your code.

Comment: Can `domain` have special characters OR only letters?

Comment: Domain will have only letters !

Comment: Case 2 looks good but not allowing space(spacebar). Sorry didnt mention that before.

Comment: Case 2 Is Awesome Now! A big thanks for that! Testing case 1 Now.

Comment: Case1 - Not behaving properly.NOT allowing me to enter anything. PLease help

Comment: case 1 I am checking in server side. So its coming as Domain\\user987. Also Case 2 allows backslash which is not required.

Comment: ok edited case2. Case 1 allows: `exp1.test('abcd\\user001');` at present. What's the problem?

Comment: tried the case 1 in http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html. But the text doesnot match

Comment: Thnaks anubhav. The demo site is great especially the explanation provided. I used something else for the case 1. Will test this one as well after weekend.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41323/discussion-between-bose-geek-and-anubhava)

Comment: @Bose_geek: I just came online. Are you still having issues?

Comment: I would request you to kindly have a look into the comment above your comment which contains the link to discussion.

Comment: First thing you need to understand how SO works. You ask a question and people answer it. If you're satisfied with any answer then accept the answer. After that if you've another question then create a new question. Looking at history of this comment thread it looks like as if you've outsourced your problem to me without even clearly explaining your problem in your question. I have been very patiently answering all your doubts but I guess it has reached a point where we need to move on.